# Jmeter Current Thread Number?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I am using a Thread Group with Number Of Threads = 5 with an HTTP request.

In the request I want to include a parameter with the value of the thread number, e.g.,

```
"pageno": ${threadno}
```

I want to get the thread number like `${threadno}`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The thread number is available as:

```
${__threadNum}
```

See: [functions reference](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

Answer (score 43):

While the above-mentioned `${__threadNum}` will work in many places within jMeter, you'll need to use something else where it is not allowed, e.g., script elements within Pre/Post-Processors.

This answer explains how to get thread number or count within such a script in jMeter.

To get the number of the current thread (out of 5 in your case) use `ctx.getThreadNum()` which will get the number of the thread.

To get the total number of threads being used by jMeter you can use `ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads()` or `ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads()` for total active threads.

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum()
https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/AbstractThreadGroup.html

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use the documented `${__threadNum}` function?

Comment: Yes: there are at least two spaces: a) the input-boxes of the GUI forms within the jMeter elements: There the `${__threadNum}` is sufficient, yes. But b) there is also the scripting area, mainly JSR223/groovy: There the programmatic approach `ctx.getThreadNum()` is needed. Instead of the pre-chewed "variables", programmatically, one get power to do almost whatever.

Comment: In groovy there is also the option to use a GString to evaluate the function: `log.info("thread(${__threadNum})")`

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for the number of active threads in the entire test plan, not just a particular ThreadGroup.

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads())}
```

Answer (score -2):

`${__threadNum}` does not work well alone.

You will need use ${__eval(${__threadNum})}. 
Try to use this:

```
int threadNum=ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads();
```

ctx is from JmeterContext

Comment: Why would you need to eval a number? `__threadNum` as documented works just fine. Also, the number of threads is not the same as the current thread number.